# I am getting a null pointer error when I am allocating space for an array in C

Tags: c, malloc

I am creating an array for N elements and trying to allocate space for it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int numthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    int* res = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numthreads);
    for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
            res[i] = 0; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
        printf(res[i]);
    }
```

I would expect to see an array of `numthreads` zeros but I am getting an invalid write error. I am doing this on Visual Studio 2019 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Uh-oh! That's not how `printf` works: The `f` in `printf` is for "format" and the first argument must be a format string: `printf("%d\n", res[i])`. Please enable warnings to catch such errors.

Comment: You should also test the return value of `malloc` to make sure it succeeded.  It might fail if `numthreads` is accidentally set to some unreasonably large number.

Comment: OT: regarding; `int numthreads = atoi(argv[1]);`  Never access beyond `argv[0]`  without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected command line parameter

Comment: OT: regarding: `int* res = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numthreads);`  1)  In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int numthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
    int* res = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * numthreads);
    if(res==NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
            res[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numthreads; i++) {
        printf("%d ",res[i]);}
        return 0;
    }
```

this may help you.

Comment: yeah I tried that and it isn't showing as `NULL` so it looks like visual studio is just sensitive.

Comment: if this issue is from visual studio. i recommend for you atom.it is very powerful and fast.and if you want really  work with c.try to use it in linux. more powerful,detailed .amazing tools and so on .

Comment: regarding: `printf("error\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  When the error indication is from a C library function, Then also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  for non-C library functions: `fprintf( stderr, "your error message\n" );`  for C library functions: `perror( "your error message" );`

Comment: Regarding; `if(res==NULL)
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }`  The code must not continue executing the following statements. so after reporting the error, call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`